# Switch eth0 to eth1 after restarting

Tags: 14.04, mac

I Have eth0 with the Original MAC And eth1 With another MAC After Restarting is Switch eth0 To eth1 Or eth1 to eth0 I want the same a choose After Restarting Not Up And Down ( eth0 , eth1 )

I use ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0):

Names for interfaces are configured in the file: `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`

You may edit this file to customize what names are given to network interfaces when the computer boots.